# Cannot make YouTube comments in Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox, youtube, comments

So, whenever I click on a button on YouTube to reply to a comment, this happens:

[image: Comment box doesn't open all the way]

I used to be able to click the Reply button a second time and it would open for me (still didn't look right), but Google seems to have "fixed" the "bug" that allowed me to comment.  I do have Google+ set up and everything.  Is there anything at all I can try besides hacking with the YouTube API?

Comment: Does this happen in a [new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)?

Comment: It seems to work fine without AdBlock Plus in a new profile, but when I enable AdBlock I can reply normally.  The only thing that changes is the "alerts" drop-down stops working with AdBlock.  I'm not getting rid of AdBlock though, without it my computer is very slow.

Comment: The AdBlock Plus [forum](https://adblockplus.org/forum/) could be helpful.